# How to get the logged in user id

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

sorry for not specifying question properly as i dont even know what should i write on there but here is my problem.

I have 2 tables `users` and `organiser` and they both are using same desktop system for different privileges on my project and have 2 different `login` pages.

Now the confusion is that I want to introduce another feature to list the advertisement on website and i want both of the users to post ad on website. For that sometimes i need to get the `id` and other details of the logged in user,so what should i do here to know which `user` is logged in or `organiser` is logged in?

Should i make any changes in database? or add any extra field in the `advertisement` table which indicates which type of user has created that record??? I am using `yii2` framework if that matters.

Here is the code of `frontend` configuration file in `yii2`

```
return [
'id' => 'app-frontend',
'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
'defaultRoute' => 'event/index',
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_frontendUser', // unique for frontend
        ],
    ],


    'session' => [
        'name' => 'PHPFRONTSESSID',
        'savePath' => sys_get_temp_dir(),
    ],
    'request' => [
        // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'YNdaEYHtai',
        'csrfParam' => '_frontendCSRF',
    ],

   ],
 ];
```

Comment: explore PHP session variables. See this manual page on [Session Introduction](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

Comment: Are you setting `$_SESSION` with the id? Can you show some code?

Comment: @Drew usually when i write `yii->$app->user->id` i get the logged in users id?

Comment: @wogsland i have added code

Comment: sound more like a statement than a question. One either maintains class references (or non OOP), or they swing for letting PHP tell you who you are thru `$_SESSION`. Adds the concept of *state* to an otherwise stateless environment

Comment: @Drew so you are saying that i should provide some information in $_SESSION to differentiate `user` or `organiser` by assigning information while they logs in??

Comment: yes, I am suggesting you should explore it. Maybe the `yii` way is better. I don't know `yii`

Answer (score 3):

For adding field or method to User class you can or extend the User class ([User doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html)) , or create an your new User class implementing the identity interface ([Identity doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-identityinterface.html)) .

depend by your experience or ability.

(You can also evaluate extensions related to User management)

For accessing the current  logged user you can use

for username

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->username
```

for id

```
Yii::$app->user->id
```

Comment: so if i wants to implement multiple login in frontend than i have to define 2 modules one for `user` and other for `organiser` and afterwards i can get the logged in user like `Yii::$app->user->id` or `Yii::$app->organiser->id` ?

Comment: The module for user is already definined in Yii  and  if you need  another one you could  try adding a proper module for organizer. I suggest you to evaluete the RBAC or AUTH management also and then use the role for different access to the application..